# Lexical Analyzer not printing all tokens and lexemes

Tags: java, switch-statement, lexical-analysis

It seems when there is an operator or parenthesis it won't print what comes last. For example when taking the "(47+12);" It will output:

```
Next token is: LEFT_PAREN   Next lexeme is (
Next token is: INT_LIT      Next lexeme is 47
Next token is: ADD_OP       Next lexeme is +
Next token is: INT_LIT      Next lexeme is 12
Next token is: RIGHT_PAREN  Next lexeme is )
```

and skip the semicolon.

```
package lexPackage;
 
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Lex {

    static final int MAX_LEXEME_LEN = 100;
    static Token charClass;                            // Compare to enum to identify the character's class
    static int lexLen;                                 // Current lexeme's length
    static char lexeme[] = new char[MAX_LEXEME_LEN];   // Current lexeme's character array
    static char nextChar;
    static Token nextToken;
    static int charIndex;

     //Tokens and categories
    enum Token {
        INT_LIT,
        ADD_OP,
        LEFT_PAREN,
        RIGHT_PAREN,
        DIGIT,
        SEMICOLON,
        UNKNOWN,
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String line;

        try {

            // For each line, grab each character 
                line = "(47+12);";
                charIndex = 0;
                
                if (getChar(line)) {
                    // Perform lexical analysis within array bounds 
                    while (charIndex < line.length()) {
                        lex(line);
                    }
                    
                }
        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
    
    private static Token lookup(char ch) {

        switch (ch) {
        
        case '(':
            addChar();
            nextToken = Token.LEFT_PAREN;
            break;

        case ')':
            addChar();
            nextToken = Token.RIGHT_PAREN;
            break;

        case '+':
            addChar();
            nextToken = Token.ADD_OP;
            break;
    
        case ';':
            addChar();
            nextToken = Token.SEMICOLON;
            break;
            
    /*
     * No default case - each lexeme should fall
     * within one of the categories set above.
     */
        }

        return nextToken;
    }

    /************* addChar - a function to add nextChar to lexeme *************/
    private static boolean addChar() {
        
        if (lexLen <= 98) {
            lexeme[lexLen++] = nextChar;
            lexeme[lexLen] = 0;
            return true;
        }
        
        else {
            System.out.println("Error - lexeme is too long \n");
            return false;
        }
    }

    
    /************* getChar - a function to get the next character in the line *************/
    private static boolean getChar(String ln) {
        

        if (charIndex >= ln.length()) {
            return false;
        }
        

        nextChar = ln.charAt(charIndex++);

        if (Character.isDigit(nextChar)) {
            charClass = Token.DIGIT;
        } 
        
        
        
        else {
            charClass = Token.UNKNOWN;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /************* lex - a simple lexical analyzer for arithmetic expressions *************/
    public static Token lex(String ln) throws IOException {
        
        lexLen = 0;

        
        switch (charClass) {
        // Parse integer literals 
        case DIGIT:
            nextToken = Token.INT_LIT;
            addChar();
            
            if (getChar(ln)) {
                while (charClass == Token.DIGIT) {
                    addChar();
                    
                    if (!getChar(ln)) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                
                if (charClass == Token.UNKNOWN && charIndex == ln.length()) {
                    charIndex--;
                }
            }
            break;
            
         // Parentheses and operators 
        case UNKNOWN:
            lookup(nextChar);
            getChar(ln);
            
            break;
            
        default:
            nextToken = Token.UNKNOWN;
            break;
            
        } // End of switch 
        
         // Print each token and its respective lexeme 
        System.out.printf("Next token is: %-12s Next lexeme is %s\n", String.valueOf(nextToken), String.valueOf(lexeme, 0, lexLen));

        return nextToken;
    } // End of function lex 
}
```

Comment: Well, `getNonBlank()` could be an obvious culprit.  Could you show its source code?

Comment: @markspace added to the original post

Comment: Honestly your code is kind of convoluted and there's still a lot that's not being shown.  I think it would be best if you produced a runnable example that shows the error.  [mcve]

Comment: @markspace I updated it. Tried my best to take out as much as I can.

Comment: The short answer is that when you call `lookup()` your index `charIndex` is already equal to 7, meaning it points to the semicolon.  Then when you call `case UNKOWN` in `lex()` you call `addChar()` which advances the index to 8, which is past the end of the string, so parsing stops.  I think using static variables is sloppy and you need to restructure your code to be easier to read, it seems to rely on side effects too much.